# Does changing the scrypt salt have security implications?

Tags: aes, salt, scrypt

I'm using `scrypt` to stretch a user-supplied password for use as an AES encryption key. The data that's being encrypted with the AES encryption never changes.

I'm aware that if the user changes the password, the random salt must be regenerated.

I'm wondering if there are any security implications for unnecessarily changing the salt. i.e changing the salt without changing the password.

Note that this is in an environment where we're assuming all past and present copies of the salt and encrypted data would be available to an attacker.

Comment: You're talking about changing the salt when you have plaintext access to the user's password, e.g. a login, right?  Just not during a password change?

Comment: @PwdRsch Correct, we'd have the plaintext password when we're doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there are no implications. From what i know, scrypt is not vulnerable to differential cryptoanalysis.